# Foundation: force breakpoint for a specific part of the page

Tags: html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I want to display something like a preview of some content which contains a foundation grid (row small-12 medium-6 columns etc).

**Is there a way to force this content to be displayed as it would be displayed at a different breakpoint than the actual one?**

For example, suppose a user loads the page and the actual breakpoint is the large one. How would I show a specific content as it would appear to the medium/small breakpoint without asking the user to resize the window?

I can think of an iframe solution but I'd rather not got that way.

Comment: Are you trying to test your responsive design?

Comment: Not exactly, users will create pages dynamically and while designing I want them to be able to see how it looks without changing the browser's window.